# DRV8833 does not work with output of hobby RC receiver

Tags: dc-motor

I'm trying to drive the DAGU robot chassis with Pololu engine drivers. Driver requires - at minimum - the following connections:

- VIN (for the motor)
- GND
- AIN1
- AIN2
- AOUT1
- AOUT2
- GND (for the logic)

I have made the following connections:

- LiPo 2S provides ~7V, which is converted by unused ESC with BEC to 5V (powers up everything) (After connecting, I'm getting around 4.5V under load, maybe it's important)
- FrSky X8R receivier acts as PWM generator; 1st channel is connected to AIN1, AIN2 is shorted to GND to provide logical 0; RX is powered from 5V, GND is common;
- AOUT1 and AOUT2 are connected to the engine
- VIN and GND of the driver are connected to 5V provided by the ESC and GND, respectively

Specific parts I've used are:

- [Pololu DRV8833](https://botland.com.pl/pl/sterowniki-silnikow-dc/546-pololu-drv8833-dwukanalowy-sterownik-silnika-108v-12a.html)
- [Dagu DG012-ATV](https://botland.com.pl/pl/podwozia-robotow/1975-dagu-dg012-atv-multi-chassis-4wd-4-kolowe-podwozie-z-napedem-6952581600794.html?search_query=dagu&results=63)
- [Taranis X8R RX](https://77hobby.pl/frsky-x8r-odbiornik-816ch-z-telemetria-p-3.html)

After powering the whole thing up and turning TX on, I only hear low buzzing noise from the engine, which changes a little when I push the TX stick up and down.

You can hear the buzzing on the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQYu7ONXzVo

I replaced the engine driver with another one (identical) with the same effect.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the engine turning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are literally doing wrong is using an incompatible selection of parts.

Your DRV8833 is an H-bridge driver where the motor is only on when some combination of the inputs are on.  Typically they would either be set in a chosen direction configuration *constantly* or more commonly for a percentage of time via pulse width modulation.

In contrast your Radio Set communicates *commanded* servo positions, not motor drive states.  You may be getting a little confused, because this communication is also a pulse width modulation.  But it is a pulse width with a very slight duty cycle - typically only 1-2 mS of on time, out of a 20 mS or so (50 Hz) repetition rate, because in the classic implementation the 4-7 channels were transmitted over the air one after another in turn.

This low duty cycle signal is not designed to feed an H-bridge, but rather to *command* either a classic servo error amplifier, or more likely today an MCU in a servo or ESC.  If you try to feed it directly into an H-bridge, you maximum on time would be maybe 10%, and that's not really enough to move a motor, especially at a very low 50 Hz frame rate.

You need to either *buy* or *build* an ESC to drive your motor.  Selection of such is explicitly off topic here, and designing such is *too broad* to fit within the bounds of a Stack Exchange question.  If you look in RC hobbyist publications or forums you will find that people have occasionally made DIY efforts over the years which you might learn from.

Comment: The set I've prepared was only a PoC to check the components. The target setup will include Teensy 3.5 generating PWM on one of GPIO outputs and I can set (almost) any PWM frequency I want (I guess 10Hz+)

Comment: Well, instead of testing the components, you've presumably learned that the idea won't work without the MCU in the middle to translate servo signals into motor duty cycle...  Typically you want much higher output PWM rates in the hundreds to thousands of Hertz.

Comment: Would the Teensy board be enough to generate proper output to drive the motor? With proper program, obviously.

Comment: It's far more than you need actually (with care almost any cheap/compact MCU would do), but if it is what you have on hand it would presumably work.

Comment: I plan to use the Teensy to drive the whole robot, not only wheels, that's why I want to use one. I'll test the setup tomorrow, thanks for help!